# Cauchy Schwarz inequality and absolute value

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

Here's the inequality: 
$$|\langle u,v\rangle|\le\|u\|\cdot\|v\| $$

Why on the LHS there's an absolute value? We know that $\langle u,v\rangle \ge 0$ Isn't it redundant?

Comment: No $<u,v>$ is just a complex number- need not even be real, let alone $>0$.

Comment: Oh, but it does true for $\left<v,v\right>$. Right?

Comment: Yes- that's part of the axioms of inner product. Note that in that case C-S inequality is actually an equality.

Comment: @voldemort : Except that one should write $\langle u,v\rangle$ rather than $<u,v>$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: justice on your side, @MichaelHardy

Comment: Let's try a little experiment: ${<}u,v{>}$ and $<u,v>$.  You see, when it's coded as {<}u,v{>}, then there's not as much space between the symbols and the letters as when one codes it as <u,v>. There's a common-sense reason for that.  But still one should write $\langle u,v\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: True. Sorry for the bad formatting in the comments. I was a bit sloppy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\langle u,v\rangle$ need not be even a real number in general. For example, consider $\mathbb{C^2}$, $u=(1,i)$, $v=(0,1)$.

Even if you are dealing with real inner product spaces, the inner product of $u$ and $v$ need not be positive.

For example, in $\mathbb{R^2}$ take $u=(1,0)$, and $v=(-1,1)$.